# For aws dynamodb, does a scan of the hash_key use an index?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

The hash_key takes the form of `daily|<YYYY-MM-DD>`.

Whats the most efficient way to fetch a range of dates?

We cannot do a query. Well not for the whole resultset in one go. Although a loop and a series of queries for each exact key might be the 'correct' answer?  Is that the best solution?

If we do a scan on the hash_key, would it use an index?  Would that actually be somewhat efficient?
eg: `hash_key in ('daily|2022-12-07', 'daily|2022-12-08')`

The sort_key is a user identity_id.

Answer (score 1):

Best approach is to do a query for each PK, possibly in parallel. If the average item collection size is large this is even pretty efficient.

Think of DynamoDB like a hashtable storing sorted lists. You want all the values associated with certain hash table keys. So you need to do the lookups.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree.  Afaikt, scanning, even on the hash/sort keys seem to just as slow and expensive as the other attributes.  Might you know anything about that stuff?

Comment: A scan touches everything, by definition. Make sure DDB is the right database for your use case.